# releasing Jedis pool

Tags: redis, garbage-collection, dispose, jedis

In most examples including [this](https://gist.github.com/deepakverma/9aa4dc04ded700603a8ef24eececf5d3) Jedis example the Jedis pool is created in the try..catch parenthesis which I think disposes it:

```
try(Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource())
{
    some code
}
```

For me this is not possible because I need to throw errors while still using the Jedis pool, depending on result from Redis. So for my this is just

```
Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()
```

Question is how best to dispose the object? Is it jedis.disconnect? jedis.quit? jedis = null?

There are some similar questions but not exactly same. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680696/jedis-not-releasing-connections-jedis-leaking-connections-jedis-connection-p) about error it gives, [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230503/how-jedis-pool-works) about increasing pool, [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569901/use-connection-pool-with-jedis) about threading.

Comment: The link you gave is not *official* example. Please be careful and respectful about stating so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `jedis.close()`. See [Jedis - When to use returnBrokenResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082163/jedis-when-to-use-returnbrokenresource)

You used to be expected to use `jedisPool.returnBrokenResource(jedis)` or `jedisPool.returnResource(jedis)`, but `jedis.close()` takes care of it.

See [Jedis.java](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.java#L3498).

```
Jedis jedis = null;
try {
    jedis = jedisPool.getResource();

...
}catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
...
}catch (Exception e){
...
} finally {
    if (jedis != null)
        jedis.close();
}
```